# using gsub in ruby strings correctly

Tags: ruby, string, gsub

I have this expression:

```
channelName = rhash["Channel"].gsub("'", " ")
```

it works fine. However, I can only substitute 1 character with it. I want to add a few more characters to substitue. So I tried the following:

```
channelName = rhash["Channel"].gsub(/[':;] /, " ")
```

This did not work, that is there was no substitution done on strings and no error message. I also tried this:

```
channelName = rhash["Channel"].gsub!("'", " ")
```

This lead to a string that was blank. So absolutely not what I desired.

I would like to have a gsub method to substitute the following characters with a space in my string:

```
 ' ; :
```

My questions:

1. How can I structure my gsub method so that all instances of the above characters are replaced with a space?
2. What is happening with gsub! above as its returning a blank.

Comment: Whitespace matters a lot in a regular expression...

Comment: @meagar Unless you use the `x` option correct? http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Regexp.html#label-Options

Comment: Why not use [`String#tr`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-tr) for simple things like this?

Comment: @muistooshort awesome, thanks. Yes I didnt even look at that method. This is why I like SO, there is always a new way of solving a problem to learn about....... Thanks! I will try that. 

One quick question. Is the "tr" method more efficient than gsub?

Comment: `tr` is probably faster than `gsub` but (a) regex engines can be surprisingly fast, (b) the difference is probably irrelevant for all practical purposes, and (c) you could always [benchmark it](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/index.html) and see.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your second attempt was very close. The problem is that you left a space after the closing bracket, meaning it was only looking for one of those symbols **followed by a space**.

Try this:

```
channelName = rhash["Channel"].gsub(/[':;]/, " ")
```

Comment: Ditto to this answer. Also, `string.gsub!("'", " ")` will return nil if no substitutions were performed, hence why you are probably seeing `rhash["Channel"] = nil`. See: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-gsub-21

Comment: @jslivka thanks for that clarification +1. I was wondering why that was happening.

Answer (score 5):

This does not answer your question, but is a better way to do it.

```
channelName = rhash["Channel"].tr("':;", " ")
```